# Huge sorted list of random numbers

Tags: java, scala, random

I need to create a method which returns a number sampled of some random distribution where every time call the method the returned number is bigger than any previously returned numbers.

Or, in other words, i need an iterator for a sorted list of random values.

Unfortunately the list is too big to be created in memory as a whole. The first idea i came up with is to divide my value space into buckets, where each bucket contains values in some range [a, b).
Say my list has N elements. To create a bucket i would sample my distribution N times and put each value in the range [a, b) into the bucket. Values outside that bucket would be discarded.

This way i could create a new bucket each time i iterated over the last and keep memory consumption low.

Yet, as i am not an expert in statistics, i am a little afraid this will somehow screw up the numbers i get. Is this an appropriate approach? Is it important to use the same exact distribution generator (an instance of org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.RealDistribution) for each bucket?

**Update:** It seems i did a bad job of explaining what kind of random number i am talking about.

My numbers form a sample of a random distribution like for example a normal distribution with a mean of m and variance of v, or an uniform distribution or exponential distribution.

I use those numbers to model some behavior in a simulation. Say i want to trigger events at some times. I need to schedule billions of events and the times those events are triggered must form a sample of a random distribution.

So if i derive my next number by adding a random number to my previous number i indeed get a sequence of growing random numbers but the numbers wont form a sample of my distribution.

Comment: What you are asking for is definitely not trivial. I expect the procedure, when it exists, you must use will be very dependent on the distribution you are sampling from.

Comment: See my solution below. It depends solely on the requirement that the same sample of a distribution can be created several times by using a fixed seed when crating the sample.

Answer (score 3):

On you can say what are the requirements of your random generator.

> I need to create a method which returns a number sampled of some random distribution where every time call the method the returned number is bigger than any previously returned numbers.

You can do something like.

```
private long previous = 0;
private final Random rand = new Random();

public long nextNumber() {
  return previous += rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
}
```

The details depend on how you want to model your random numbers.

Comment: Good idea, but the numbers produced by nextNumber() will not form a sample of my distribution. See my update for a clarification.

Comment: I suspect you only need the time difference to be a truncated normal distribution.  A full normal distribution goes from negative infinity to positive infinity.  Delays in real systems don't follow a normal distribution or anything like it (which make standard deviations rather meaningless ;)

Comment: What i need is a finite sample of some distribution ;-) . I simulate user requests, a normal distribution could, for example, be useful to simulate behavior around a special event.

Comment: I would expect a poisson distribution after a special event. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution  This is easier to model incrementally.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the poisson distribution. Reading the article made me reframe my problem. By modeling the times between events instead of modeling the time from some fixed start time i can just compute one delay after the other, nothing needs to be stored in memory.

Answer (score 1):

If the list is too big to store in memory, you can use a database and read/write batches of list items to and from the database.

This way you only ever need to store one batch in memory at any one time.

Comment: Is there a data structure that would handle this efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

I would start off by creating a variable and storing your first random number, then generate another random number, compare them and if it is larger save it in both large storage and ram, repeat as the next random number would be compared to single value in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a random number to the previously generated number. So you have to keep in memory only the number you generated in the iteration step before.

Answer (score 0):

`SamplePartitioner` is a class which divides a sample of some distribution in several partitions of fixed size, which are returned, one by one, by `nextPartition()`.

`nextPartition()` creates the whole sample on every call but stores only the smallest `partitionSize` values, which are bigger than the biggest value of the last partition. By using a fixed seed, `nextPartition()` creates the exact same sample each time it is called.

```
class SamplePartitioner(sampleSize: Long, partitionSize: Int, dist: RealDistribution) {
    private val seed = Random.nextInt
    private var remaining = sampleSize
    private var lastMax = 0.0

    def nextPartition(): SortedSet[Double] = remaining.min(partitionSize) match {
        case 0 => SortedSet.empty[Double]
        case targetSize =>
            dist.reseedRandomGenerator(seed)
            val partition = fill(sampleSize, SortedSet.empty, targetSize)
            lastMax = partition.last
            remaining -= partition.size
            partition
    }

    private def fill(samples: Long, partition: SortedSet[Double], targetSize: Long): SortedSet[Double] =
        samples match {
            case 0 => partition
            case n =>
                val sample = dist.sample()
                val tmp = if (sample > lastMax) partition + sample else partition
                fill(n - 1, if (partition.size > targetSize) tmp.init else tmp, targetSize)
        }
}
```